# Which frameworks on free web server in mid 2011 for HTML5 web sockets?

Tags: java, frameworks, websocket

I plan to use web sockets in 2011 when official Firefox 4 will be released. I have a background in Java and Spring but I can choose also another language or platform.

Comment: You should know that WebSockets will be disabled by default in FF4.  https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=616733

Comment: Specifically it is disabled in FF4 beta 8 (but can be enabled via about:config). Many applications using WebSockets have the Flash web-socket-js fallback so this will only affect performance for those apps. Note that this is not a security bug in the browser or WebSockets, but a concern that transparent proxies will be compromised more easily with WebSockets. Also, the spec is moving fast. I wouldn't be surprised to see this turned back on by default (with a new more secure handshake) early on after FF4 ships.

Answer (score 0):

[Kaazing](http://tech.kaazing.com/documentation/dragonfire/kaazing-architecture-overview.html) could be probably one of the most promising technologies that focuses on html5 websockets regarding Java.